# Time efficiency of binary tree traversal

Tags: java, performance, time

This is a leetcode question. "Given a binary tree and a sum, find all root-to-leaf paths where each path's sum equals the given sum." But my code can't pass test case because of time exceeded limit. But the solution code(https://oj.leetcode.com/discuss/15169/14-line-solution-in-java-using-recursion) can pass the test case. I don't figure out is there any big difference with two version codes?

My code:

```
public class Solution {
  List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
  public List<List<Integer>> pathSum(TreeNode root, int sum) {
    if (root == null)
        return res;
    List<Integer> t = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    has(root, sum, t);
    return res;
  }

  public void has(TreeNode root, int sum, List<Integer> t) {
    if (root == null)
        return;
    if (root.left == null && root.right == null && sum == root.val) {
        t.add(root.val);
        res.add(t);
        return;
    }
    t.add(root.val);
    has(root.right, sum - root.val, t);
    has(root.left, sum - root.val, t);
    return;
  }
}
```

Solution:

```
public class Solution {

    public static List<List<Integer>> pathSum(TreeNode root, int sum) {
      List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
      if(root==null) return list;
      if (root.val==sum && root.left==null && root.right==null)   {
        list.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        list.get(list.size()-1).add(root.val);
        return list;
      }
      list.addAll(pathSum(root.left, sum-root.val));
      list.addAll(pathSum(root.right, sum-root.val));
      for(List<Integer> l:list)
          l.add(0, root.val);
      return list;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

List is an object. If you pass List to your method, it will be treated as a local variable within that method. At the end of your method, that local variable will be garbage collected (deleted).

You add a node to your List and then call the method recursively passing that List. When you eventually hit the trivial case (you hit a leaf ). Your method will end and return to continue running the (same) method which called it. You're not returning anything and the instance of List will be garbage collected (deleted). So that means the leaf is missing from your List (because the local List that had it is deleted). It will continue doing so and and your pathSum method will eventually return an empty List. I can't tell why it exceeds the time limit but your code is not correct.

Note that in the Solution the method returns the List in which the new node is added. So the method that called it has it stored. In your implementation, you return nothing and the method that called it didn't store the List with the new Node, and is therefore garbage collected.

I hope this clarifies your problem. If not feel free to let me know.

Comment: When my code hit a leaf, and I will save the result into a global variable 'res'. I think my code is right for the logic.

Comment: No that is not true, you aren't storing anything in res. Your idea is right, but you implement it wrong.

Comment: Oh wait, I had a quick look at your code again and you're right. Hold on let me find out your error.

Comment: You are right Auberon, my code has error, for the parameter t, if I change it, I will get the changed one even if I go back from my recursion. So what I modify is to do a copy of (t), and do changes on the copy one. And then I pass the test case. Thank you for your help.